# Use of the word 한걸요

Tags: spoken-korean, korean-to-english

When and why do we use '**한걸요**'? Like I have seen sentences like

그대의 꿈이 너무 소중**한걸요** (Your dream is so precious)

and 그대의 꿈이 너무 달콤**한걸요** (Your dream is so sweet).

I looked up the meaning of 한걸요 and according to Papago app it means 'I did it'.

I am new to learning korean.

감사합니다!

EDIT (from comments by OP): This is part of the lyrics for the song 도시의 천사들: http://gasazip.com/1242598

Comment: Is this written like this somewhere? Did you copy/paste this or did you write down what you heard?

Comment: It is from a song - Angel in the city by Lucia

Comment: there are some typos as mentioned in the answer by @lingodeerapp. Here are the lyrics,  for other readers of this question: https://klyrics.net/lucia-dosiui-cheonsadeul/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

The word you are trying to translate, 소중한걸요, is actually composed of three parts: 소중하-(소중하다), -ㄴ걸, and -요.

It would be easy for you to check out the meaning of 소중하다, so I'll focus on explaining the latter two.

-ㄴ걸 is used for verb declension, often used for light interjections. For example,

> 와, 정말 대단한걸! Wow, that's really great!

and -요 is one of the most frequently used postpositions, which makes the whole sentence sound a bit more polite, but informal. You'll see these a lot in Korean lyrics.

Answer (score 2):

It is an expression used when you say a newly learned fact with admiration. It can be used to explain one's thought or argument, or give a reason for it.
This form of speech is also used in the lyrics and poems.
ex)
이것은 너무 쓴걸요. /
이 영화 정말 슬픈걸요. /
그게 사실인걸요. /
저는 지금 너무 행복한걸요./
그대 생각에 잠이 안 오는걸요./
저는 어른이 아니라 학생인걸요. /
아침을 안 먹었더니 벌써 배가 고픈걸요.

*I corrected some typos in the sentences.
그대의 **꿈**이 너무 소**중**한걸요 (Your dream is so sweet)
그대의 **꿈**이 너무 달콤한걸요 (Your dream is so precious).